# About Java Positioning

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change jButton position to right, when the jPanel appears, but the only change is jPanel appears and disappears.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    n++;
    if((n % 2) == 1){
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        jButton1.setLocation(200, 0);
    }

    if((n % 2) == 0){
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        jButton1.setLocation(0, 0);
    }
}
```

But if I write just the section below, double click will make the change of jButton position. I want to see the changes from one click.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){  
    jPanel1.setVisible(true);
    jButton1.setLocation(200,0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a layout manager.

Comment: Use appropriate layout managers, [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and I'd recommend a `CardLayout` for switching between views, [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the Border Layout manager with Flow Layout.

for more info go to this tuturial [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)